# Filter out object elements that do not have associated products in DB

Tags: javascript

I have an object containing a list of categories, and I want to remove the individual elements *(categories)* that have no associated products in the products table.

How would I loop through the `cats` object, read the `catid` property for each element, search the products table and get all products matching that `catid` value, then filter out from the original object elements that do not have any products for the associated category?

I'm using nodejs with knex as the middleware to access the MySQL table... but that should be irrelevant to the question of "how do I filter certain elements out of the object"?

```
const cats = await knex('categories').select('catid', 'catname', 'desc', 'refnum');
const newCats = cats.filter(async (item) => {
   const prods = await knex('products').select('prodid').where({ category: item.catid });
   if (prods.length > 1){
      console.log('ThisCat:', item.catname, ' and LENGTH:', prods.length);
      return d;
   }
});
console.log({ newCats}); //SHOULD have dropped elements with no associated products
```

My `ThisCat` console.log correctly skips the categories without an associated product, but the `newCats` object still contains all the original entries.

Comment: Why do you do this in JS instead of SQL?

Comment: Your concrete problem is that your filter method is `async`. It's always returning a `Promise` which is truthy. But you really shouldn't do it this way. It's really slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter call back function needs to return true or false. you can do it like:

```
const newCats = cats.filter(async (item) => {
const prods = await knex('products').select('prodid').where({ category: item.catid });
if (prods.length > 1){
  console.log('ThisCat:', item.catname, ' and LENGTH:', prods.length);
  return true;
}
return false;
});
```

or just use the if condition:

```
const newCats = cats.filter(async (item) => {
const prods = await knex('products').select('prodid').where({ category: item.catid });
return prods.length > 1      
});
```